# Distribute equitably NA values to each column values

Tags: r, dataframe

In a dataframe column I have 778 NA values.

I have 21 unique values in this column.

I want to distribute equitably NA values to all these 21 values.

Example:

```
37 NA values = 1, 37 NA values = 2 etc...
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you can add an small reproducible example for data it will be easier to get answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `sample`. Suppose your column name is `v` then you can try as:

**Option#1:**

```
v[is.na(v)] <- sample(v[!is.na(v)], length(v[is.na(v)]), replace = TRUE,
      prob = rep(1, length(v[!is.na(v)])))
```

**Option#2:** Another more accurate option can be achieved using `rep_len` with argument `length.out` as:

```
v[is.na(v)] <- rep_len(v[!is.na(v)], length(v[is.na(v)]))
```